# Undefined Reference when Invoking Function of One Object from Another Object

Tags: c++, hashtable, undefined-reference

I am having trouble figuring out how to fix this **undefined reference** error. I have the class `hashTable` and in its `insertWord(string)` function *definition*, I invoke a function of a linkedList object that is in a vector. The problem is I get this error:

**Error:**

```
C:\Users\...\hashTable.o:hashTable.cpp|| undefined reference to `linkedList::linkedList()'|
C:\Users\...\hashTable.o:hashTable.cpp|| undefined reference to `linkedList::appendNode(std::string)'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

---

I think it may be something to do with scopes for the linkedList instances/functions within the hashTable class. Also, I have a linkedList.cpp and a linkedList.h that both work 100% perfect (LOTS of tests) so I don't believe showing the linkedList's literal code will be beneficial.

Some of my code:

**hashTable.h**

```
///hashTable.h

#ifndef HASHTABLE_H_EXISTS
#define HASHTABLE_H_EXISTS

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "linkedList.h"

using namespace std;

//class hashTable
class hashTable{
    private:
        vector < linkedList > hTable; //our hashTable "storage system" ---> vector of linkedList objects
    public:
        hashTable();
        hashTable(string);
        void init_hashTable(); // general initializer function
        int  getIndex(string); //our "hashing" function
        void loadFile(string);
        void insertWord(string); // insert word into: vec< LList(word) >
};//end hashTable def

#endif
```

**hashTable.cpp**

```
///hashTable.cpp

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "hashTable.h"
#include "linkedList.h"

using namespace std;

//class hashTable functions
hashTable::hashTable(){
    //constructor
    hashTable::init_hashTable();

}//end constructor

hashTable::hashTable(string fileName){
    //overloaded constructor
    hashTable::init_hashTable();
    hashTable::loadFile(fileName);

}//end overloaded constructor

void hashTable::init_hashTable(){
    // general inializations

    // add a linkedList to the vector for each english letter
    for (int i = 0;i < 26;i++)
        hashTable::hTable.push_back( linkedList() );

}//end init_hashTable

int hashTable::getIndex(string word){
    //gets index for hTable

    // Returns ascii integer value of capitalized
    // 1st letter minus ascii value of 'A'.
    return toupper( word.at(0) ) - 65;

}//end getIndex

void hashTable::loadFile(string fileName){
    // loads words by line from file: fileName

    // our token
    string token = "";

    // input file stream
    ifstream file;
    file.open( fileName.c_str() );

    // while not at endOfFile
    while ( !file.eof() ){

        // token gets current line/word
        getline(file, token);
        // if line is not empty
        if (token != "")
            // insert word into hashtable
            hashTable::insertWord(token);
    } // end while

}//end loadFile

void hashTable::insertWord(string word){
    // Appends word to a LinkedList of cooresponding
    // hash code position in the hTable (a=0,b=1,...,z=25).

    // get index for LL in hTable
    int hashCode = hashTable::getIndex(word);

    // adding the word to our chosen linkedList
    hashTable::hTable[hashCode].appendNode(word);

    /* TAKE NOTE:                               //
    \\      hTable[hashCode] is a specific      \\
    //      linked list from the hTable vector  */

}//end insertWord



// testing harness...
int main(){

    hashTable tbl("words.txt");

    return 0;
}//end main
```

Comment: You need to link the linked list object file in when building as well.

Comment: As in the linkedList.o file? how would I do that? I know I included the header files for the linkedList class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out:

1) You can make a makefile; I use PuTTY to accomplish this for example.

2) Since we want the makefile to be "extension-less", producing the makefile in Unix is ideal.

3) here's how you would write it in this case (in PuTTY, using vi editor) :

```
vi makefile [PRESS ENTER]


HT: hashTable.o linkedList.o main.o
          g++ hashTable.o linkedList.o main.o -o HT
hashTable.o: hashTable.cpp hashTable.h linkedList.h
          g++ -c hashTable.cpp
linkedList.o: linkedList.cpp linkedList.h
          g++ -c linkedList.cpp
main.o: main.cpp hashTable.h linkedList.h
          g++ -c main.cpp
clean:
          rm -f *.o

:wq  [PRESS ENTER]  // this will save and quit from the vi editor
```

The basic setup here is:

```
Label: all object files seperated with a space
       g++ all object files seperated with a space -o Label
objectFile.o: objectFile.cpp  dependencies.h ...etc.
       g++ -c objectFile.cpp
//...do above 2 lines for every object file(.o) you have
clean:
       rm -f *.o // get rid of extension of your make file
```

Then after writting your makefile, you just run it by typing 'make' in the directory. You will then see your Label (the one used in your makefile) in the same directory as the makefile. then you just run your "all-in-one" program by typing this:  `./Label`

## --EDIT--

If you don't want to make a makefile, you can defenitely just type in PuTTY the following:

```
 g++ -o HT hashtable.cpp linkedList.cpp main.cpp   [PRESS ENTER]
```

However, you will have to type this every time you alter your code as opposed to the makefile.

Comment: you don't *have* to have a makefile (although it's a useful idea), you could have written `g++ -o HT hashtable.cpp linkedList.cpp main.cpp`

Comment: @M.M Thanks! I totally forgot about that as I haven't used PuTTY in a while. Edited.